# Java: Map with any enum as key

Tags: java, generics, collections, enums

How can I declare Map whose key can have any enum?

For example, I have two enum Fruit and Vegetable.

How can I declare map where key can be both Fruit and Vegetable, but only enumerations, not Object?

I mean, something like

```
Map<???, String> myMap...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. You can use `java.lang.Enum` as key.

   ```
   enum Fruit {
       Apple
   }

   Map<java.lang.Enum<?>, String> mp = new HashMap<>();
   mp.put(Fruit.Apple, "myapple");
   ```
2. Create interface to be implemented in your enums. This method give you more control.

   ```
   interface MyEnum{}

   enum Fruit implements MyEnum {
       Apple
   }

   Map<MyEnum, String> mp = new HashMap<>();
   mp.put(Fruit.Apple, "myapple");
   ```

Comment: I would suggest to use an EnumMap instead of a HashMap, as it is optimized for maps with enum as keys.

Answer (score 8):

You need to have a common supertype for your two enums if you want to declare a map where instance of two types can be the key. A map can only have one key type, but if you have one type with two subtypes, then that is ok.

You cannot change the superclass for enums (it's always `java.lang.Enum`), but you can make them implement interfaces. So what you can do is this:

```
 interface FruitOrVegetable {
 }

 enum Fruit implements FruitOrVegetable {
 }

 enum Vegetable implements FruitOrVegetable {
 }

 class MyClass {
     Map<FruitOrVegetable, String> myMap;
 }
```

The question is: what is the shared behaviour of the enums Fruit and Vegetable that you can include in the interface. An interface without behaviour is pretty pointless. You'd constantly need to do `instanceof` checks and casts to treat something as a `Fruit` or `Vegetable`.

Maybe in your case, you actually need a single enum `FruitOrVegetable` - if you want to be able to treat them interchangeably.